# Wordpress remove_action issues

Tags: php, wordpress

To preface this, I am well aware there are multiple questions on SO that cover this issue.  However, after going through many of them and attempting their solutions, I still haven't been successful in removing the action.  Some of the SO questions that I have tried are:

[need help removing action from plugin file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25356365/need-help-removing-action-from-plugin-file)

[remove_action() not working in WordPress plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673984/remove-action-not-working-in-wordpress-plugin)

[How to remove a WordPress action which uses the current object - $this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22143334/how-to-remove-a-wordpress-action-which-uses-the-current-object-this)

I am working on creating a child theme in Wordpress that is utilizing a third party plugin for adding software license capabilities to WooCommerce.  In trying to customize this plugin, I am looking at removing a action added by the plugin, and replacing it with a modified version.

The add_action call that I am trying to remove is:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_end', array($this->functions, 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_end'), 99, 3 );
```

This add_action is called in the class `WOO_SL_front`, which defines `$this->functions = new WOO_SL_functions();`

In my attempt to remove this action, I have used the following function:

```
//Remove WOO_SL email and order action...
//Add customized version of email and order action
function swsint_remove_actions(){
    global $wp_filter, $WOO_SL_functions;
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_end', array($WOO_SL_functions, 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_end'), 99);

    error_log(print_R($wp_filter, true));
}
add_action('init', 'swsint_remove_actions');
add_action('woocommerce_order_item_meta_end', 'swsint_woocommerce_order_item_meta_end', 98, 3);
```

With this attempt, I have not been able to remove the action.  The function still executes.  As you can see, I print the list of registered Wordpress actions to the error_log.  Through this, I know the action has been added prior to me attempting to remove it, and I believe I have confirmed I have the correct class listed in the remove_action function.  The pertinent output is here:

```
[woocommerce_order_item_meta_end] => Array
        (
            [99] => Array
                (
                    [000000005807010900000000491e34d0woocommerce_order_item_meta_end] => Array
                        (
                            [function] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => WOO_SL_functions Object
                                        (
                                            [query_vars] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [software_license] => view-license
                                                )
                                         )
                                    [1] => woocommerce_order_item_meta_end
                                )
                            [accepted_args] => 3
                        )
        )

            [98] => Array
                (
                    [swsint_woocommerce_order_item_meta_end] => Array
                        (
                            [function] => swsint_woocommerce_order_item_meta_end
                            [accepted_args] => 3
                        )
        )
    )
```

From this output, I am unsure what to make of the `000000005807010900000000491e34d0woocommerce_order_item_meta_end`.  It clearly shows the class which the function is from is `WOO_SL_functions`, and the function name is `woocommerce_order_item_meta_end`.  However, I have tried all variations I can think of for calling the remove_action function:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_end', array($WOO_SL_functions, 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_end'), 99);
remove_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_end', array('WOO_SL_functions', 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_end'), 99);
remove_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_end', array($WOO_SL_front->functions, 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_end'), 99);
remove_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_end', array('WOO_SL_front->functions', 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_end'), 99);
remove_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_end', array('WOO_SL_functions::woocommerce_order_item_meta_end'), 99);
```

Any insight anyone can provide is much appreciated!

Comment: its an anonymous function see here http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/57079/how-to-remove-a-filter-that-is-an-anonymous-object

Comment: @David - Worked perfectly.  Thanks very much!!